# Handling select condition dynamically

Tags: sql, oracle, select, plsql

I have a procedure like

```
Procedure P_GENDER_REP
 (
  l_province  IN  varchar,
  l_district  IN  varchar,
  l_village   IN  varchar,
  l_tribe     IN  varchar,
  l_clan      IN  varchar,
  l_refcursor out sys_refcursor
 )
```

And i have a select Query inside the procedure like this

```
select a.province,a.DISTRICT,a.VILLAGE,a.TRIBE,a.CLAN,b.cdr_data 
from itaukei_data_store b,itaukei_data_store_key a 
where a.reference_no = b.reference_no and a.record_no = b.record_no and a.province = l_province 
  and a.district = l_district and a.village = l_village and a.tribe= l_tribe 
    and a.clan = l_clan      
order by a.DISTRICT,a.VILLAGE,a.TRIBE,a.CLAN;
```

Now i need a select query handling the inputs given.For example if only l_province is given,i need to ignore all the other where conditions dynamically. Pls help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you do this by adding `OR l_variable IS NULL` to every conditions:

```
select a.province,a.DISTRICT,a.VILLAGE,a.TRIBE,a.CLAN,b.cdr_data 
from itaukei_data_store b INNER JOIN itaukei_data_store_key a 
ON a.reference_no = b.reference_no 
  and a.record_no = b.record_no 
  and a.province = l_province 
WHERE l_district IS NULL OR a.district = l_district
  and l_village IS NULL OR a.village = l_village
  and l_tribe IS NULL OR a.tribe= l_tribe
  and l_clan IS NULL OR a.clan = l_clan
order by a.DISTRICT,a.VILLAGE,a.TRIBE,a.CLAN;
```

However, this may sometimes affect performance. You will be better off to use IF for each of the combinations. Alternatively, you can try to use a CASE statement, that supports the short-circuiting, like this:

```
select a.province,a.DISTRICT,a.VILLAGE,a.TRIBE,a.CLAN,b.cdr_data 
from itaukei_data_store b INNER JOIN itaukei_data_store_key a 
ON a.reference_no = b.reference_no 
  and a.record_no = b.record_no 
  and a.province = l_province 
WHERE a.district = CASE WHEN l_district IS NULL THEN a.district ELSE l_district END
  and a.village = CASE WHEN l_village IS NULL THEN a.village ELSE l_village END
  and a.tribe = CASE WHEN l_tribe IS NULL THEN a.tribe ELSE l_tribe END
  and a.clan = CASE WHEN l_clan IS NULL THEN a.clan ELSE l_clan END
order by a.DISTRICT,a.VILLAGE,a.TRIBE,a.CLAN;
```

You have a third option. You can use `COALESCE` in place of a `CASE`, like this:

```
select a.province,a.DISTRICT,a.VILLAGE,a.TRIBE,a.CLAN,b.cdr_data 
from itaukei_data_store b INNER JOIN itaukei_data_store_key a 
ON a.reference_no = b.reference_no 
  and a.record_no = b.record_no 
  and a.province = l_province 
WHERE a.district = COALESCE(l_district, a.district)
  and a.village = COALESCE(l_village, a.village)
  and a.tribe = COALESCE(l_tribe, a.tribe)
  and a.clan = COALESCE(l_clan, a.clan)
order by a.DISTRICT,a.VILLAGE,a.TRIBE,a.CLAN;
```

Try each one and see which one performs better. BTW, I have also changed your FROM clause from comma delimited lists of table to a standard INNER JOIN. Please make a habit to use JOINs, as it is now considered a "best parctice"

Comment: "However, this may sometimes affect performance." I'm guessing you know more about it than I do, but I thought if you did the null check first, then the DB wouldn't bother with the other side of the `OR` (short circuiting). In the worst case scenario, are we talking a performance hit that would be detectable to a user on a single call, or would it take several calls to the SP before the user would notice?

Comment: Unfortunately, almost all RDBMS do not support short-circuiting. The "better quality" (like Oracle) ones can optimise the query. If you want I can update the question to put the checking for NULL in front, but I feel it should not make any difference. I believe the only way to achieve the short-circuiting is to use CASE. I will update the answer to include the option to use CASE statement.

Answer (score 0):

Given examples are of SQL Server,
First Way, Simple If

```
Declare @l_province int
Declare @l_district int
Declare @l_village int

If @l_province is not null and @l_district is null  and @l_village is null -- Only l_province is given
Begin
    select a.province,a.DISTRICT,a.VILLAGE,a.TRIBE,a.CLAN,b.cdr_data 
        from itaukei_data_store b,itaukei_data_store_key a 
    order by a.DISTRICT,a.VILLAGE,a.TRIBE,a.CLAN;
End
Else
Begin
    select a.province,a.DISTRICT,a.VILLAGE,a.TRIBE,a.CLAN,b.cdr_data 
        from itaukei_data_store b,itaukei_data_store_key a 
    where a.reference_no = b.reference_no 
            and a.record_no = b.record_no 
            and a.province = l_province 
            and a.district = l_district 
            and a.village = l_village 
            and a.tribe= l_tribe 
            and a.clan = l_clan      
    order by a.DISTRICT,a.VILLAGE,a.TRIBE,a.CLAN;
End
```

---------------------Second Way Using OR , AND

```
select a.province,a.DISTRICT,a.VILLAGE,a.TRIBE,a.CLAN,b.cdr_data 
        from itaukei_data_store b,itaukei_data_store_key a 
    where (
            (
                (@l_province is not null and @l_district is null  and @l_village is null) -- Only l_province is given
                AND
                (1=1)
            )
            OR
            (
                (@l_province is not null and (@l_district is not null  OR @l_village is not null))
                AND
                (
                        a.reference_no = b.reference_no 
                        and a.record_no = b.record_no 
                        and a.province = l_province 
                        and a.district = l_district 
                        and a.village = l_village 
                        and a.tribe= l_tribe 
                        and a.clan = l_clan 
                )
            )
            OR
            (
                (@l_province is null)
                AND
                (
                        a.reference_no = b.reference_no 
                        and a.record_no = b.record_no 
                        and a.province = l_province 
                        and a.district = l_district 
                        and a.village = l_village 
                        and a.tribe= l_tribe 
                        and a.clan = l_clan 
                )

            )
        )   
    order by a.DISTRICT,a.VILLAGE,a.TRIBE,a.CLAN;
```

Actually to make it simple in stored procedure, I will suggest you to bring one parameter that where clause should be applied or not! For calculating that variable, you need to write some code either in code behind or at start of stored procedure. It will make life easy.

Comment: SQL Server syntax. Please change it to PL/SQL, as this is what OP has asked

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another hack to the mix.

if you don't have similar values for each of the columns you can use [coalesce](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm#SQLRF00617)

```
select  a.province,a.district,a.village,a.tribe,a.clan,b.cdr_data 
from    itaukei_data_store b,itaukei_data_store_key a 
where   a.reference_no = b.reference_no 
and     a.record_no = b.record_no 
and     coalesce(a.province,a.district,a.village,a.tribe,a.clan) = 
        coalesce(l_province,l_district,l_village,l_tribe,l_clan)
order by a.district,a.village,a.tribe,a.clan;
```

Coalesce return the first not null value in a list

Answer (score 0):

you can nvl the parameters, such that when they're set then they're used otherwise the matching value from the compared table is taken.. should have the desired effect:

```
select a.province,a.DISTRICT,a.VILLAGE,a.TRIBE,a.CLAN,b.cdr_data
from itaukei_data_store b,itaukei_data_store_key a 
where a.reference_no = b.reference_no 
and a.record_no = b.record_no 
and a.province = nvl(l_province, a.province)
and a.district = nvl(l_district, a.district)
and a.village = nvl(l_village, a.village)
and a.tribe = nvl(l_tribe, a.tribe) 
and a.clan = nvl(l_clan, a.clan)
order by a.DISTRICT,a.VILLAGE,a.TRIBE,a.CLAN;
```