# SQL Server: Subquery in "boolean" WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery, where-in

I have T-SQL query (SQL Server 2008/2012) that uses the following construct:

```
WHERE (@param1 IS NULL OR column1 = @param1)
AND (@param2 IS NULL OR column2 = @param2)
AND (@param3 IS NULL OR column3 = @param3)
```

This works fine and automatically optimizes out any of the AND'ed parts of the WHERE clause with NULL params.

But when I do this same thing with a subquery, the optimizer appears to still execute the subqueries even when the param is NULL:

```
WHERE 
    (@param1 IS NULL OR column1 IN (SELECT column 
                                    FROM table 
                                    WHERE column = @param1))
    AND (@param2 IS NULL OR column2 IN (SELECT column 
                                        FROM table 
                                        WHERE column = @param2))
    AND (@param3 IS NULL OR column3 IN (SELECT column 
                                        FROM table 
                                        WHERE column = @param3))
```

My question is why would the optimizer even consider the "IN" SELECTs since the the fact that the param is NULL should have already "short circuited" that part of the query?

Comment: As far as I know there is no `short circuit` in SQL Server. You need to use `CASE` where you can achieve a `short circuit`  behaviour

Comment: Read my [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22978759/handling-select-condition-dynamically/22978868#22978868) for an example of usage of CASE

Comment: @cha: I'm pretty confident that the first code example works as expected; I didn't invent this, but I've made use of it for some time and the execution plan proves the expected behavior. The second code example also works, but the execution plan shows that the subqueries are still being executed.

Comment: @user640466 . . . What makes you think that the first query does any optimization of the `or` clauses?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Looking at the execution plan and what indexes are used in the query based on what params are NULL or not confirms it; here is one of many references to this kind of construct: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/09/18/sql-conditional-where-clauses.aspx

Comment: @user640466 . . . That article explicitly argues against the point that your first query is optimized.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Hmmm. I don't think it argues against it (see the original article that it references here: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2003/11/14/513.aspx), it just discusses some additional optimizations that can be used with ranges and LIKE operators. In any case, there is little doubt that the (...IS NULL OR...) construct works as expected--the execution plan confirms it.

Answer (score 0):

@user640466: I think if you add OPTION (RECOMPILE) query hint the bad plan will go away , reason being that query optimizer  have to evaluate the IN clause to get the ProductID value whereas in case of OPTION (recompile) it can sniff the run time value. Pls see below a working copy from Adventure works :

```
CREATE PROC MyTest
@ProductID INT ,
@Name NVARCHAR(50),
@ProductNumber NVARCHAR(50)
AS
SELECT * 
FROM Production.Product 
WHERE 
(ProductID IN (SELECT ProductID FROM Production.Product WHERE ProductID = @ProductID ) OR @ProductID IS NULL)
AND 
(Name IN (SELECT Name FROm Production.Product WHERE Name = @Name) OR @Name IS NULL)
AND 
(ProductNumber IN (SELECT ProductNumber FROM Production.Product WHERE ProductNumber = @ProductNumber)  OR @ProductNumber IS NULL)
--OPTION (RECOMPILE)
GO
```

IF you execute the Proc : EXEC Mytest 1,NULL,NULL you will get a lengthy plan however alter the sp and uncomment the OPTION (RECOMPILE) you will get the nice plan.

Comment: I'll experiment with that, but even so, it seems like the optimizer could easily avoid the subquery even without a recompile; why even execute the subquery if the OR logic makes the result of the subquery irrelevant?